Issues with Integrating a Custom Block into a Minecraft Mod(texture)
I am creating a mod for Minecraft and I made a custom block that extends BaseEntityBlock. I encountered a problem with the block's texture: when I place it in the world, the transparent part of the block appears black, but when I hold it in my hands, everything looks fine.
public static final RegistryObject<Block> GARDEN_BLOCK = registerBlock("garden_house",
        () -> new GardenBlock(BlockBehaviour.Properties.copy(Blocks.GLASS)));



forge 1.20.1

Ignore the inaccurate closing message (for when it appears), but you might want to try asking on [so] with the minecraft-forge tag as this site's main audience aren't developers (even though we get Minecraft-related programming questions anyway)

In [gamedev.se], it is minecraft-modding but is not as active on [so]
